# What is the use case of skipping method execution in around advice?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I understood what `@Around` Advice does, and when we need to share Before and after state then we can use it, and we call also skip method execution. My question is why Spring given us this power to skip method execution and what is the use case of skipping method?

Comment: If you don't want to run the method based on arbitrary conditions and don't want to, or cannot, change the original calling code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: And my question is when to skip it , i know i can change arguments.

Comment: *When* to skip it? When you don't want to run it?

Answer (score 1):

Side effects as *Nándor* said are one thing. Maybe you even want to replace the return value altogether, possibly because there is a bug in a class you do not have the source code of or for other reasons:

**Buggy Java class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Earth {
    public String getShape() {
        return "disc";
    }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The Earth is a " + new Earth().getShape() + ".");
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
The Earth is a disc.
```

**Bugfix aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Earth;

public aspect BugfixAspect {
    String around() : execution(* Earth.getShape()) {
        return "sphere";
    }
}
```

**Console log with aspect applied:**

```
The Earth is a sphere.
```

Answer (score 0):

Method calls usually have side effects. Whenever you decide in your aspect that those side effects are undesirable for whatever reason, it's a valid use case to skip executing the original execution. This includes use cases for caching for example, when the side effects are not in terms of data, but execution time.

Comment: Thank you ! Its very satisfactory answer .

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the need of readOnly attribute in spring tranaction how it good for performance, why it called hints .?

Comment: It's a hint, meaning implementations are not required to respect the attribute. An implementation may throw an exception in case you're trying to execute a write operation in a transaction marked as read only, but you shouldn't rely on a specific implementation's behavior if you want to stay portable across persistence providers. I think it won't affect performance in any significant way.

Comment: What the use case of supports and never propagation , please help